# Detect when RecognitionListener has stopped on Android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I'm making an assistant app and I'd like it to start recongnition of commands when I say something. As I can't understand how to make it with `AlwaysOnHotword` (the official way (?) but private and not available to normal apps - by the way, I have root access and the app is installed on the System partition), I went with PocketSphinx.

I have it listening in background for the right words and when it detects the words, I stop it and start Google Speech Recognition (more accurate). When Google's finishes, I need to start PocketSphinx's again. I'm using `SpeechRecognizer` and `RecognitionListener` for Google recognition. On the latter, there are 2 functions which I'd expect to always be called, but they're not - `onError()` and `onResults()` (if I don't say anything, none is called, only if it detects some sound or something, I'm not sure). So I can't rely all times on them. `onEndOfSpeech()` is always called, but the other 2 can be called after it (because this is just an indicator - the process might continue if there was an error or if there are results, if none of those, this is the last called function), so I can't rely on that one to enable PocketSphinx, or they'll be both enabled and that can't happen (only one listening on the microphone). Am I missing something? Does anyone know how I can be sure the `RecognitionListener` is over so I can start the other one? Because even if the microphone is no longer in use when `onEndOfSpeech()` is called (didn't test that), the apps speaks, so if I start PocketSphinx, it might recognize the words from what the app speaks, so I'd like to start one only after everything of Google part is finished. Can this be done somehow?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** actually `onError()` is called if I don't say anything AND I don't make any noise. `onError()` and `onResults()` are not called both if I make noises but don't say anything --> it has to detect partial results but the `matches.get(0)` must be an empty string (I print `matches.get(0).toLowerCase()` and I get nothing out of it in these cases, and I check and nothing here is null) - if this happens, it won't call neither `onError()` nor `onResults()`, which I'd expect to be always called in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a completely good thing to do, but it's what I thought on after months of not coming back to the app.

```
Thread reset_pocketsphinx_error = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (onEndOfSpeech_last) {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= reset_pocketsphinx_error_time + 6000) {
                        onEndOfSpeech_last = false;
                        reset_pocketsphinx_error_time = 0;
                        start_pocketsphinx(false, false, true);
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The thread is always waiting until `onEndOfSpeech` is called (`onEndOfSpeech_last` goes true when it's called) and when it is, it starts actively waiting for 6 seconds to pass since the call to `onEndOfSpeech()` (5 seconds of my supposed network timeout, which I have no idea if it's a good value or not, plus 1 second if the timeout doesn't take exactly 5 seconds) - `reset_pocketsphinx_error_time` variable is set equal to `System.currentTimeMillis()` on `onEndOfSpeech()`. If the value of `onEndOfSpeech_last` didn't change by then, then the function will suppose the error happened and will restart PocketSphinx voice recognition. The value of `onEndOfSpeech_last` is set to false on the declaration, on `onBeginningOfSpeech()`, on `onError()` and on `onResults()`.

The problem I see with this is in case the Internet connection is slow and it was processing the voice data when this stopped it. But I'll also suppose 5 seconds is enough of timeout and also that I'll not be on that case (I also have the prefer offline extra on Android's `SpeechRecognizer` for it to go on offline whenever possible).

If by chance anyone has a better solution, I'd appreciate (that's why I'm not accepting this as the final answer - aside from not being a very good solution).

**PS:** I used `while(true)` on the thread because I believe I already tried interrupting threads and getting them back to work and it didn't work, so I just let it running forever like I did on another thread on the app, and while there's nothing to do, it waits 2.5 seconds. When there's stuff to do, it just waits 0.5 seconds to be active on doing what it has to do. Then it gets back to rest.